# Jquery call a parent div to show loader

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a series of divs with same class that originate from a FOREACH. Each one contains a form and and an ajax call using jquery.

When submimitting a form I want a loader to appear in that div only but instead it appears in all of them or not at all if using the example below. Of course I am doing something wrong but not sure what. I have is this:

```
$('.form-approve').unbind('submit').submit(function () {

        var item = $(this).parent('div');

        item.next('.loading').show();

// etc. etc
```

I am sure how to show the loader ony in the div where the form has been submitted. Can someone please help?

The page contains the following html:

```
 <?php foreach ($this->records as $r):?>
 <div class="requests">
 // show a name etc.
 <div class="log"> // this div is shown using a toggle
<form class="form-approve" etc.>
....
</form>
<div class="loader"></div>
</div>
<? endif; ?>
```

The above of course is repeated many times in a page.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the job:

```
$('.form-approve').unbind('submit').submit(function () {
        $(this).next('div.loader').show();
});
```

the `div` you want to display is next to the form itself, so `$(this).next('div.loader')` should properly target it — no need to retrieve it through the parent

edit. just to be sure you should have that code for each form, like in this way

```
$('.form-approve').each(function() {
     $(this).unbind('submit').submit(function () {
         $(this).next('div.loader').show();
     });
})
```

Comment: I must be making a msitake the form submits but loader no show.

Comment: it's difficult to tell if you don't post a fiddle showing your attempts

Comment: @firefiter you mistyped the class name: you wrote `form-aprrove` instead of `form-approve` (not easy to see)

Comment: There isn't much to show is all there I have tried your last post but still no show.

Comment: @Calderan: it was just a typo here. On original code is ok besides the ajax call in it works fine.

Comment: so please, update your question with a demo page so we can see

Comment: I have added a bit more. But is all there really I don't think is the html page the problem although there are two divs as you can seee in the edited part.